# How to post data in ajax from bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem in bootstrap modal. I want to add caption of an image using bootstrap model.

For the modal section I have done this,

```
<!-- Modal content Start-->
 <form method="POST">
   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $i;?>" role="dialog">
     <input type="hidden" id="image_id" name="image_id" value="<?php echo $Array->image_id;?>" >
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Image Caption</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" placeholder="Caption" value="<?php echo $Array->image_caption;?>"/>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn_caption">submit</button>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- Modal End Here  -->
```

For the ajax part I have done this,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("button#btn_caption").click(function(){
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
     alert(postData);
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "process.php",
       data: postData,
        success: function(msg){
            //alert('successfully submitted')
        },
        error: function(){
          alert("failure");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

For the process.php file I put these lines,

```
<?php 
include('require/admin_header.php');
if (isset($_POST['caption'])) {
    $caption=strip_tags($_POST['caption']);
    $image_id=strip_tags($_POST['image_id']);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    // Data base update code
    echo 'Update Done';
}?>
```

Now, the problem is the database is not updating with the value. `<?php echo $Array->image_caption;?>` it print the value from the database in the modal. But when I do this `alert(postData);`, it alert nothing. Can any one help me that where I am making the mistake?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: As you posted the code for form tag i can not see "Id" atreebute. just add id attribute and try with give below answer it should work

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var postData = $(this).serialize();
```

with

```
var postData = $("#form_id").serialize();

<form method="POST" id="form_id">
</form>
```

Comment: I already did this thing. In this place if I alert the `postData`, it show the data like, `image_id=37&caption=`

Comment: Did you get the caption value from this $("#caption").val() @Avishake

Comment: I did. But the data is not coming.

Comment: what does it output <?php echo $Array->image_caption; ?>. whether it is nil or some value?

Comment: Am asking about the output of this line  <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" placeholder="Caption" value="<?php echo $Array->image_caption;?>"/> in the browser

Comment: It is printing `Test`. I add this word in the database.

Comment: you are getting this <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" placeholder="Caption" value="Test"/> in the browser right

Comment: Yes. And I just solve the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the question like this way,

This is the modal part,

```
 <!-- Modal content Start-->
       <form id="contactForm1" action="process.php">
     <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $i;?>" role="dialog">
    <input type="hidden" id="image_id" name="image_id" value="<?php echo $Array->image_id;?>" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Image Caption</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" placeholder="Caption" value="<?php echo $Array->image_caption;?>"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn_caption">submit</button>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  <!-- Modal End Here  -->
```

This is the ajax part,

```
<script>
// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( "#contactForm1" ).submit(function( event ) {
// Stop form from submitting normally
event.preventDefault();
// Get some values from elements on the page:
var $form = $( this ),
 id = $form.find( "input[name='image_id']" ).val(),
 caption1 = $form.find( "input[name='caption']" ).val(),
 url = $form.attr( "action" );
// Send the data using post
var posting = $.post( url, { image_id: id, caption: caption1} );
// Put the results in a div
 posting.done(function( data ) {});
});
</script>
```

And the PHP part is like this,

```
<?php include('require/admin_header.php');
if (isset($_REQUEST['caption'])) {
$caption=$_REQUEST['caption'];
$image_id=$_REQUEST['image_id'];
// Update SQL
echo 'Update Done';
}?>
```

Thanks for those who interest to solve the question. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, in your ajax code:

```
var postData = new FormData($("#form_id")[0]);
```

and in your open form tag, you must add enctype="multipart/form-data" to upload image.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_id">
   <input></input>
</form>
```